# Wkhtmltopdf tiny pdf when content is long

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to generate pdf from html using wkhtmltopdf (php).
I'm not very why this happens, but when html page content is long, i get a tiny pdf like in the image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/95PxQ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using word-wrap in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

For others looking for a solution, this is the css I'm using in gimli (https://github.com/walle/gimli) to fix the issue.

https://github.com/walle/gimli/commit/39981dda4de003902748c3e089aa42da809af6a9#L0R145